# Multiple records with GET and PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Trying to figure out how to do this on multiple records. I am trying things out, looking at reference but not understanding how to get it working, firstly here Here is my code that works:

My href link in `loop`.

```
<a href="search.php?city=<?= $row['city'] ?>">city</a>
```

My PHP

```
if (isset($_GET['city'])) {

$city = $_GET['city'];      
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * from table WHERE city = ? ");
$stmt->execute(array($city)); 
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) : //loop starts

} else { //html content }
```

---

The above simply pulls `city` records that are being called via a URL variable in my first loop. What If wanted to repeat this multiple times with different URL Variables to generate different results from the database. So instead of just getting one record like my above code I want to get 2 more, here is a below example of what I mean.

Example Href links in a `loop` with the URL variables city, name country:

```
<a href="search.php?city=<?= $row['city'] ?>">city</a>
<a href="search.php?name=<?= $row['name'] ?>">name</a>
<a href="search.php?country=<?= $row['country'] ?>">country</a>
```

Example of PHP which is not working, but getting these URL variables and passing them through to mysql by SELECT, hopefully you get what I mean):

```
if (isset($_GET['city'], $_GET['name'], $_GET['country'])) {

$city = $_GET['city'];  
$name = $_GET['name'];
$country = $_GET['country'];

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * from table WHERE city = ? OR name = ? OR country = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($city, $name, $country)); 
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) : //loop starts

} else { //html content }
```

Any advice on how to achieve this would be appreciated, also if there is an easier way to do this or my current code is not up to scratch, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: You will need to explain in more detail what you require.

Comment: @david Hey David, if you see my above example, you should get the idea. Sorry if it was hard to understand, English is my second language. Basically I want to GET multiple URL variables but i can only seem to get one working (see first example). The last example is how in my head I assume it would be. Multiple GET in the isset etc.

Comment: @davidstrachan added more content to better explain myself. ^

Answer (score 2):

```
if (isset($_GET['city'])||isset($_GET['name'])||isset($_GET['country'])) {

       echo $city= $_GET['city'];

       echo $name=$_GET['name'];

       echo $country $_GET['country'];
       }
```

Comment: Don't know where you're going with this. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking to put the url's into an array so that you can use them later? If so, you could do something like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['city'], $_GET['name'], $_GET['country'])) {
$city = $_GET['city'];  
$name = $_GET['name'];
$country = $_GET['country'];

//added:
$url_array = array();

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * from table WHERE city = ? OR name = ? OR country = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($city, $name, $country));
//$row changed to $rows 
while($rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) : //loop starts
    //foreach added
    foreach($rows as $row){
        $url_array[] = $row;
    }

} else { //html content }
```

I hope that helps?

Comment: Hey man, thanks for taking you time to help me out. I am looking to imitate the first example (first block of code I posted) just add the extra fields (name, country). My first example works, just adding these extra 2 are not working for me. I tried your code with no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, I'm a little confused on what you want to do. Do you want a list of url's...what is the actual end product that you're looking for?